# Adding a legend to a plot of a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm not sure how i would add a legend to my set of data . I've tried a few online guides but none seem to be of any help.

```
L_list = np.linspace(0, 500, 6) #kg
plt.hold(True)
theta = 84
print("Begin simulation...")
print()
for i in L_list:
    print("Mass = ", i, "kgs")
    X, Y, t = FlightEnvelope(i, theta)
    #T, M, t = FlightEnvelope(L, i)
    plt.plot(X,Y)   



print()
print("Simulation complete.")
print()
print("=============================================================")
print("=============================================================")
plt.ylabel("Height of Rocket (m)")
plt.xlabel("Horizontal distance traveled (m)")
plt.title("Trajectory of Rocket")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The code isn't runnable.

Comment: so whats your out put ? and whats the desire out put that you want !

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
plt.legend(["A", "B", "C"])
```